# Firebase Storing User Emails but Not Any Other Details?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following a YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-RE1QuUWPg) to help me set up my Firebase realtime database, I have watched the video twice now and have found no errors in my code so wondering if someone can help.

Firebase is storing the user email address within the 'Authentication' tab, but is not storing the name, password, or age in the realtime database.

I have set all the usages to allow read/write also, and my dependencies are all in check.

```
TextView login;
private Button signup;
private EditText etFullName, etAge, etEmail, etPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logIn);
    signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signUp);
    etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullName);
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    signup.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.signUp:
            registerUser();
            break;
    }
}

private void registerUser() {
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String fullName = etFullName.getText().toString().trim();
    String age = etAge.getText().toString().trim();

    if(fullName.isEmpty()) {
        etFullName.setError("Full name is required!");
        etFullName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(age.isEmpty()) {
        etAge.setError("Age is required!");
        etAge.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(email.isEmpty()) {
        etEmail.setError("Email is required!");
        etEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        etEmail.setError("Please enter a valid email address.");
        etEmail.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.isEmpty()) {
        etPassword.setError("Password is required!");
        etPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(password.length() < 6) {
        etPassword.setError("Password should be more that 6 characters.");
        etPassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        User user = new User(fullName, age, email);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User has been registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Failed to register, please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Failed to register, please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

---

```
public class User {

    public String fullName, age, email;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String fullName, String age, String email) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many things that could be going on, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. Can you try these steps, and update your question with the information: 0) Are there any messages logged when the `setValue(user)` line executed? 1) if you put a breakpoint on ` if(task.isSuccessful()) {` and run in a debugger, does it reach that line? 2) Where is your Realtime Database instance located? 3) Did you (re)download the `google-services.json` after creating the Realtime Database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your comment! No messages are logged at `setValue`, the debugger reaches the first `isSuccessful` and seems to store the data correctly, however it does not reach the next instance of this function. Can you clarify what you mean by where it is located? And no I hadn't redownloaded the JSON file, but I have now and sadly it hasn't solved the issue..

Comment: For #3: when you created the database, you selected a region. Can you check what region you selected? Otherwise: can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the database? I'm specifically interested in the bottom of the console screen (as that shows the region).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen EuropeWest1, I've just read something about that causing issues, unsure how to change the region however. Can't find much online..

Comment: You can't change the region after creating the database, but that's not why I asked. Can you try specifying the database URL in your code, so `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("url here")` to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. It doesn't seem to be moving past the `setValue()` function anymore.. before it would get to the `Failed to register` toast, now it is just stuck loading, but registers email still on the Authentication tab in Firebase..

Comment: This notification comes up in the log when I run `registerUser()` - `W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.` Tried some solutions I found on another forum but nothing helped.. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: "Moving past" is a bit unclear there. When debugging asynchronous callbacks, always use breakpoints and a debugger. So now if you set a breakpoint on `if(task.isSuccessful()) {` and run in the debugger, it doesn't hit that breakpoint anymore?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It reaches that breakpoint, the first one. however does not appear to go any further than that.

Comment: It reaches `.addOnCompletedListener`

Comment: If you step through the code from there on, you can see whether the task was successful or not. If it wasn't successful, have a look at `task.getException()` as that will tell you what went wrong.

Comment: I have added an exception but it doesn't run. After `addOnCompleteListener` the debugger says 'application running' but my device is stuck on loading screen. No errors are thrown.

Comment: @FrantvanPuffelen I do however receive a new info message which says `Verification of void com.example.doggo.SignUp$1.onComplete(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task) took 106.766ms (618.17 bytecodes/s) (2776B approximate peak alloc)`

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I am just an idiot.. I had enforcement switched on in the Firebase project settings! 64 'malicious' bounces. All fixed now!

Comment: Oh wow, so this came from App Check? Good to hear you found it. I'd expect the rejection to show up on `task.getException()`.

Comment: Yup! I had 64 malicious database bounces, it was stressing me out, no errors were showing up at all! Thanks for your help regardless.